# Button style not applied during runtime

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, styles

So basically I have a button that is a sideways triangle (for a "play" button).  In the xaml design editor, the button properly displays as a triangle.  However, when I run the application, it displays as a standard bland windows button.  Here's the style:

```
    <Style x:Key="ButtonStyle1" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                    <Grid>
                        <ed:RegularPolygon x:Name="PlayerPlay" Fill="#FF080808" InnerRadius="1" PointCount="3" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" Stretch="Fill" Stroke="Black">
                            <ed:RegularPolygon.RenderTransform>
                                <TransformGroup>
                                    <ScaleTransform/>
                                    <SkewTransform/>
                                    <RotateTransform Angle="90.635"/>
                                    <TranslateTransform/>
                                </TransformGroup>
                            </ed:RegularPolygon.RenderTransform>
                        </ed:RegularPolygon>
                        <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" RecognizesAccessKey="True" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
                    </Grid>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsFocused" Value="True"/>
                        <Trigger Property="IsDefaulted" Value="True"/>
                        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True"/>
                        <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="True"/>
                        <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False"/>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

and here's the button:

```
<Button x:Name="PlayerPlay" Click="PlayerPlay_Click_1"  Content="" Margin="63.54,4.752,59.686,6.682" Style="{DynamicResource ButtonStyle1}"/>
```

any idea what's going wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: Are the style and the instance defined in the same file? Is the style defined in a ResourceDictionary? If so, how do you load the dictionary?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where have you created the style ? ex in the Windows Resources , in a Dictionary etc

If your style is in the Resources where your Button is then use StaticResource
If you use dictionary make sure that you have declare it in the App.xaml File 
ex

```
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="file_name.xaml"/>
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```

Then you can use DynamicResource to apply your style.

Comment: Holy cow, a million times thank you.  Someone else is working the UI side, and they know less xaml than I do.  Changed it to static resource and worked perfect.